# Django rest framework validation when updating nested serializer (many=True)

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Child(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    attr2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attr3 = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("attr1", "attr2", "attr3")

class Parent(models.Model):
    children = models.ManyToManyField(Child, related_name="parents")
```

Then the following serializers:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
```

When updating the parent instance with the nested (many=True) children serializer, I get a validation error:

```
The fields attr1, attr2, attr3 must make a unique set.
```

However, shouldn't the serializer skip validation for the children since they're already retrieved instances from the database?

Comment: Can you include the view and example data that you are sending in? Usually this happens because DRF thinks it needs to overwrite the relation.

Comment: I have the same problem... I think the problem in that, child serializers doesn't have instance, but I couldn't solve it.  So, if you solved this problem,  let me know please.

Comment: @KevinBrown I have wrote my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011810/when-updating-serializer-nested-serilizers-does-not-have-instance-many-true. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Felix @KevinBrown - Which version of DRF are you guys on? An [issue with nested serialization for `unique_together` fields](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/2975) has been recently resolved. If reproduced on latest (3.1.3), can you guys please write an isolated test case?

Comment: @Rongzhou did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `Nested Serializers` worked for me `many=true`. Here is my code:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parents = ChildSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('id', 'parents')

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
```

Parent model has childern field in it. In the serializer you are trying to add the same field in it. Because of this it says field need to be unique.

Comment: This wont work with unique together constraint. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to "skip" children serializer validation, or write custom serializer validation to override child serializers, by overriding `to_internal_value` of the ParentSerialzer:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)

    def to_internal_value(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # runs the child serializers
            return super().to_internal_value(*args, **kwargs)
        except ValidationError as e:
            # fails, and then overrides the child errors with the parent error
            return self.validate(self.initial_data)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        errors = {}
        errors['custom_override_error'] = 'this ignores, and overrides the children serializers'
        if len(errors):
            raise ValidationErrors(errors)
        return attrs
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
```